# Run StreamBuilder whitout putting in build method

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream, stream-builder

I have a flutter app connecting to a firestore and stream a variable in it.

Every time the variable change, my code know it and do some actions. So I have a function return a Stream, and a function use this stream to return a StreamBuilder.

When the variable change, I change the value on a ValueNotifier and calling setState().

My problem is I have to put the StreamBuilder into the build of my page to run it. I want to do the same thing with another variable but I can't do that. How can I do ?